# How to replace html button with plain text

Tags: javascript, html, button

How do you replace a button with whatever words were on the button before? I was looking at an answer to another similar question, which said to use something like:

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById("buttonId"),
mySpan = document.createElement("span");
mySpan.innerHTML = myBtn.innerHTML ;
myBtn .parentNode.replaceChild(mySpan, myBtn);
```

but that had made what other buttons do change. Does anyone know another way to change a button to regular text?

I know that that code works just by itself, but it doesn't work with my code for some reason, so I don't really care what's wrong with that code. I'm just wondering if anyone knows another way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: The above code looks fine, what's it doing>?

Comment: Make sure none of your other buttons have `id="buttonId"`

Comment: Well, there are six buttons, and whenever I apply that to one of them, all of the buttons before it get disabled. I do disable and enable buttons in my code a lot, but it just randomly disables them

Comment: J L, I know that they don't

Comment: Seems to be working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6wk56/

Comment: It works on there, but I doesn't work on my javascript. I checked about 1,000 times for errors

Comment: @user3130551: Well, something *is* wrong. But the code you posted is correct, so there is nothing we can do.

Comment: Do you know another way to do it, so that I can try that instead?

Comment: Does anyone know another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <input type="button" value="Change into Text" id="submit" onClick="change()"> <!--button input that will trigger an event named change-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

function change(){ //function to run when you click on the button...
    var buttonValue = document.getElementById("submit").value; //stores the button value
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = buttonValue; // displays the value as a plain text inside "myDiv" - removing the button input entirely 
}

</script>
```

**EDIT:**
I've just noticed you had multiple buttons in your page, which will make my previous example wrong. heres something that will make you work easier i think in case you will add extra buttons:

first heres the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li id="id_1"><input type="button" value="Change into Text" onClick="change(1)" id="button_1"></li>
        <li id="id_2"><input type="button" value="Change into Text" onClick="change(2)" id="button_2"></li>
        <li id="id_3"><input type="button" value="Change into Text" onClick="change(3)" id="button_3"></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var id;
function change(id){
    var buttonValue = document.getElementById("button_"+id).value;
    document.getElementById("id_"+id).innerHTML = buttonValue;
}

</script>
```

In the HTML part, you can create a list `(li)` of buttons if that's your layout...
each list will have its own id, in this case `id_x` that will be used later when you replace its content. each button calls a function `change(id)` while `id` is just a unique number for each button.

In the JS part, the `change(id)` gets the id of the button that was clicked, takes its value, and replaces the innerHTML (content) of the relative list items with a plain text.

Let me know if you still need any other help.

Comment: Code without an **explanation** is not an answer.

Comment: I have two questions:

Comment: 1. Does it make a difference that I'm using the button tag, and not the input tag?

Comment: 2. With my buttons, the value and id are different, so would I use the id or value in the first javascript line?

Comment: Just noticed you might need multiple buttons, heres a solution i made that might be simpler.

Comment: I have another question. That is only supposed to happen if some other certain things happen, so I have a certain part of the in an if statement, where it needs to change it. So how would I do that outside of a function?

Comment: i didnt quite understand the question, can you explain under what circumstances the buttons should be editable?

Comment: I just don't want it in a function

Comment: didnt answer my question

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are looking for *another* way to replace the buttons with plain text, well I'll show you the **jQuery** way.

### HTML

```
<div>
    <button id="btn1" class="change-button">A button with some text 1</button>
    <button id="btn2" class="change-button">A button with some text 2</button>
    <button id="btn3" class="change-button">A button with some text 3</button>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
// When we click a button with a "change-button" class
$(".change-button").on("click", function(event){
    // First we get the ID value of the clicked button
    // example: "btn2"
    var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');

    // Then we get the html value of the clicked button
    // example: "A button with some text 2"
    var buttonText = $(this).html();

    // We use the function replaceWith, to replace the button to a <span>
    // with the buttonText variable we have
    $('#' + buttonId).replaceWith("<span>" + buttonText + "</span>");
});
```

As you can see, it's a lot more cleaner with jQuery. You should try it!

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AE9Sx/) so you can test it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<script>
function fun()
{
var a = document.getElementById("hello").value;

document.getElementById("ad").innerHTML = a;
}
 </script>
 <body>
<div id="ad">
    <input type="button" value="hello" id="hello" onClick="fun()">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

sorry, edited the wrong post

Comment: Code without an **explanation** is not an answer.

Comment: The getElementById() method accesses the first element with the specified id.Each HTML element has an innerHTML property that defines both the HTML code and the text that occurs between that element's opening and closing tag. By changing an element's innerHTML after some user interaction, you can make much more interactive pages.

However, using innerHTML requires some preparation if you want to be able to use it easily and reliably. First, you must give the element you wish to change an id. With that id in place you will be able to use the getElementById function, which works on all browsers.

Comment: I hope you got the explanation. If not please tell the line which you are unable to understand.